# Yet another Apache's mod_rewrite defeated guy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've come to a point where I think I'm not allowed to understand how `mod_rewrite` works. In theory I think I got it, but just can't seem to make this work. I have the following file structure:

```
code
    -application/
    -bundles/
    -laravel/
    -public/
        -css/
        -js/
        -img/
        -index.php
    -storage/
    -.htaccess
```

Sadly, my `httpd.conf` VHost configuration has this:

```
<Directory path/to/code>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DocumentRoot path/to/code

<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

And I can't modify it to point to code/public/ so I think I could fix it with `.htaccess`. Now I've tried everything. Basically what I want to do is convert every request into `/public/index.php/($1)`, except `css, js, img` which should be converted to:

```
/public/css/($1)
/public/img/($1)
/public/js/($1)
```

So if I have `example.com/` this will change to `example.com/public/index.php` and their css, img, js etc would change to `example.com/public/css`, img, js.

**I just can't do it** :(

My `.htaccess` has taken many forms, recently I gave up everything and just look like this:

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

This of course, give me *500 Internal Server Error* because it causes loops in the rewriting (is not that clear to me anyways, but still)

So, my idea with `.htaccess` was (pseudocode):

```
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /public/css/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img
    RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /public/img/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/js
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /public/js/$1

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Any idea how can I accomplish this? I would like to understand a little what am I doing wrong. I'll love to figure out how to write good `mod_rewrite` `.htaccess` files.

I'm on Windows 7, Apache2.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need the [L] option at the end of your RewriteRules to tell mod_rewrite to exit and stop processing rules.

Comment: That won't work. The `L` flag stops the current run, but all rewritten paths must still go back through the .htaccess file from the start.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an infinite loop because every rewritten path must still go back through the httpd.conf and .htaccess directives from the top. The `L` flag is often suggested but this simply tells Apache to stop the current run; it does not stop the finished rewrite path having to go through the directives from the top.

If you want to rewrite to "/public" you need to add a RewriteCond to check that this rewrite has not already been done, otherwise the rewrite happens every time and an infinite loop occurs.

This ought to work for the "public" rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1
```

This says "if the requested path does NOT already begin with `/public/` then silently rewrite the request to prepend `/public/` to it.

It's not as clear what you're trying to do with peripheral file requests (CSS, images, etc). If you want a request for `/public/page.css` to become `/public/css/page.css` then the following ought to do it:

```
RewriteRule ^public/([^/]+)\.css$ /public/css/$1.css
```

However, I'm not seeing the benefit in doing this. I think it's better to update your page scripts or your static HTML pages and simply change them to reflect the new path structure you want to use for CSS and image files. Using mod_rewrite to avoid updating paths in pages is a bad idea (in my humble opinion) and will lead to heavier load on your server and slower request responses.

If you want more detail on mod_rewrite, see the [Apache mod_rewrite manual page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestions worked great for adding `/public/` in front of every request. The problem is, if before `/public/` comes `css|js|img` then don't do nothing, else do `/public/index.php/$1` did I explained myself?

Comment: No, I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve regarding the CSS and image/js files.